# Resgatar id passado pela URL sem usar GET

Tags: php, url

tô com uma dúvida que creio que seja simples para quase todos, porém não encontrei nenhum material que realmente me ajudasse a resolver isso.

Estou desenvolvendo um micro-serviço em php que tem como único objetivo reaproveitar um conjunto de funções em php que peguei de outra aplicação.

Até aí tá tudo certo, mas uma das funções principais desse conjunto faz uma verificação da url atual, estando ela em um formato parecido com ".../users/{userid}" para utilizar esse userid para um determinado processamento.

A dúvida é a seguinte: como faço pra que, quando eu digitar algo tipo ".../users/15" no navegador, ele redirecione me redirecione para esse arquivo de funções e jogue o valor 15 onde está "{userid}"?

**Edit 1:**Consegui resolvendo usando o método de url amigável na resposta marcada como a adequada, obrigado a todos.

Comment: No caso vc está fazendo conexao a um banco de dados ou esta tentado retornar dados de uma pagina em html? Eu dei uma procurada aqui e achei esse site http://www.mauricioprogramador.com.br/posts/como-pegar-dados-do-formulario-via-get-com-php

Comment: Não estou usando banco. O que vou fazer é pegar o id que o usuario digitar na final do url e passar para a função que descrevi ali para que ela faça uma verificação em redes sociais e retorne um resultado de acordo com o que a consulta resultar. Eu Poderia até alterar para GET mas não posso alterar o código da função pois é um código compartilhado

Comment: Em relação ao redirecionamento, vai precisar configurar o arquivo `.htaccess` para pegar toda url no php pode usar `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`. Pesquise sobre url amigável

Comment: Dei uma olhada na internet e vi que dependendo do serviço ou site, a informaçao pode ser retornada em JSON,XML entre outros.Mas tudo pelo metodo GET. Nao sei se tem como fazer do jeito que voce descreveu.

Comment: Da uma olhada na sugestāo que eu coloquei no final. Provavelmente te atenderá.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não sou muito bom em REGEX.

Se a sua url estiver tipo isso: `"www.site.com.br/algo/seila/tantofaz/{15}"`

Você pode fazer isso:

```
$string = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; // pega a url
preg_match_all ('/\{\d*\}/', $string, $matches) ; // pega o valor que está {15}
$valor = str_replace(array("{", "}"), "", $matches[0][0]); // pega apenas o numero
echo $valor; // imprime
```

Com o valor, você poderá fazer o que bem entender nas suas funções.

Você também poderia trabalhar desta forma:

`"www.site.com.br/users/index.php/{15}"`

Utilizando o arquivo no diretorio users.

**como faço pra que, quando eu digitar algo tipo ".../users/15" no navegador, ele redirecione me redirecione para esse arquivo de funções e jogue o valor 15 onde está "{userid}"**

Usando um exemplo com `explode()` sugerido pelo @Bacco seria:

**Url:** *www.site.com/users/index.php/15*

```
include("../diretorioDasFuncoes/arquivoFuncoes.php");  // inclui o arquivo que contém as funções
$string = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; // pega essa string "/users/index.php/15"
$urlParts = explode("/", $string); // transforma em array
$userid = $urlParts[3]; // recupera o valor
funcaoUser($userid); // usa a função necessária

/*

$urlParts <-- array("", "users", "index.php", 15)

  /users/index.php/15

^    ^       ^      ^
.    .       .      ....... [3]
.    .       .............. [2]
.    ...................... [1]
........................... [0]

*/
```

Comment: Também pode quebrar a url pelas barras e usar suas partes

Comment: Sim @GuilhermeCostamilam ! Eu fiz assim porque sempre terá o valor { entre chaves }

Comment: Entendi, mas onde preciso por esse código? Em um arquivo index dentro de "tantofaz"?

Comment: @matiosao quem chama as suas funções? O arquivo que chama as funções que terá que pegar esse id, verificar para que ele lança.

Comment: @matiosao pode ser no index

Comment: @matiosao  se sua aplicação estiver em diretorios, entao tera que ser no index daquele diretorio por exemplo

Comment: mas eu nao sei se vai funcionar sem url amigavel

Comment: @matiosao Amigo, se estou entendendo bem... Você precisa primeiro aprender sobre url amigável.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho no htacces apenas to filtrando pra não precisar do .php no fim do link, então vou programar o index com a função de verificação seguindo os exemplos, no caso, na pasta referente ao caminho da url que vai anteceder a id fornecida, correto?

Comment: a id é uma variável.

Comment: Quando você usa url amigável, você não está usando diretorios. o HTACCESS simula isso. Imagina que você tem essa página. `site.com/index.php?page=1`. com o htaccess ela fica assim: `site.com/1`

Comment: @matiosao é assim que vc está trabalhando?

Comment: Se você não usar url amigável vai ser complicado, seria necessário um arquivo ou diretório para cada id

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam exato.

Comment: Lembrando que não precisa ter nada especial para o URL ser amigável, e muito menos .htaccess.  Isto funciona perfeitamente "www.example.com/fotos.php/276"  - E melhor do que usar RegEx é um simples explode. - E se não quiser a extensão PHP, basta configurar o servidor para tratar arquivos sem extensão como PHP mesmo.

Comment: @Bacco vivendo e aprendendo.. "www.example.com/fotos.php/276" .. Não sabia disso! tks!

Comment: @AndreiCoelho dê uma espiada em `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` - dependendo da config,, é o que basta. Um bom teste é por uma página teste.php com um `phpinfo();` dentro e experimentar vários URLs (tipo `teste.php/a/b/c`, e acompanhar as variáveis geradas.

Comment: @Bacco muito bom! Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Pega o `explode` e seleciona a parte dos números.

Depois vc faz uma regex ou uma função que capture somente os números da string armazenados na variável.

Ficaria algo assim:

```
$url_desejada =" https://www.url.com.br/?id=0909090908";
$numeros=explode('/' , $url_desejada);
$imprime =$numeros[3];

function números($imprime)
{

    return 

      preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $imprime);
}
```

Simplificando:

```
$url_desejada =" https://www.url.com.br/?id=0909090908";
$numeros=explode('/' , $url_desejada);
```

$id= preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $numeros);

echo $numeros[3];

Boa sorte!

:)